# Current class method name as string

Tags: function, delphi, class, methods, pascal

I'm wondering if there is a way with Object Pascal to get the name of the method that is currently being executed.

```
procedure SomeClass.SomeMethod(SomeArgs...);
begin
    { This should print 'This method name is: SomeMethod' }
    WriteLn('This method name is: ' + ???);
end;
```

Looks like TObject got something similar to what I need in description but I can't make it work.

```
 public class function TObject.MethodName(address: pointer): shortstring;
```

Is that the way I should go ?
If I try `MethodName(self)`, it always returns an empty string.
How to get the pointer of the method in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about classic Object Pascal (Apple's), but Delphi/FPC:

Before D2010: There is only RTTI if the method is published, in other cases procedure name is optimized away. Unit typinfo is your friend there, and iirc the typeinfo can be gotten by using typeinfo(@TSomeclass.Somemethod).

D2010: there are options to generate more RTTI information.
See e.g. [RTTI information for method pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705071/rtti-information-for-method-pointer)

Free Pascal: 2.6.x and below, as before D2010, 2.7.x as D2010, but that is still being worked on.

Comment: I am glad to hear that this is possible, but this requires too much work, much more that it is worth for me in this case. Guess I will just declare a constant string in every method, not a big deal. I though this could be done easier.

Comment: Afaik it is a requested feature. Free Pascal has some ways for this (to insert e.g. filenames and line numbers), but not procedure/methodname yet.

Comment: However, I am still looking for a different way than RTTI / manual name passing. Maybe there is someone who knows such a method ?

Comment: Theoretical, there might be ways by accessing verbose debug info and looking the address up runtime, and caching that. But that is very compiler and -version dependent. And distributing applications with debuginfo is not popular either.

Comment: Okay then. I am trying now to use RTTI similar way to delphi ones but it only works with Published methods, I am wondering what have i missed or what am I doing wrong. GetPropList is the way i went. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Probably Marco meant published not protected. Check out how application profilers are doing this, but this probably requires debug info and some assembly. I think it is not worth the hassle.